# how can you tell if deleting a commit will delete all commits after it?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

source tree how can you tell if deleting a commit will delete all commits after it?

After members of the team push tickets, we merge them into the main branch and then delete them from the remote repository.

Do you know its safe to delete a commit so long as you see that there is a branch that comes off and goes into your main branch (like 'dev', 'stage' or 'prod' )?

Comment: git has no concept of "deleting" a commit.

Comment: I think it's quite a rare feature anyway. What would be the point?  It only **takes** diskspace (all versioning systems I know allow you to undelete a file)